# Hierarchical clustering diagram plot on scipy documentation

Tags: python, scipy

I am following the example given on the documentation that explains [how to plot a hierarchical clustering diagram](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_dendrogram.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-agglomerative-dendrogram-py) with the Iris dataframe.

On this example we can pass a parameter **p** that will cut the diagram, grouping the labels:

```
plot_dendrogram(model, truncate_mode='level', p=3)
```

Then after running the algorithm we have 2X labels and then I put `p = 2`, arriving in just X/3 leaves on the dendrogram plot.

What I want is to have this data frame that the dendrogram function plots when `p=2` that cut the labels based on the hierarchy, but I can't find how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot_dendrogram` return the dict of values used to plot the dendrogram. See 'returns' section in the documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram

Try:

```
d = plot_dendrogram(model, truncate_mode='level', p=3)
```

and inspect `d`.

`plot_dendrogram` can take an argument `no_plot=True` if you're only interested in the data and explicitly don't want it to plot the graph.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer!  But looking at what you have sent it does not have a parameter that returns all the next labels, has it? I couldn't understand this.  Example: before the plot_dendogram() the labels were [1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6] , then i set a threshold to be p = 2, so i want to have for example [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2] as return